# JWT Bearer Authentication Does not read Token from headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, bearer-token

I'm trying to authenticate with JWT Bearer in  .Net-Core, here is my startup:

```
var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

// Configure JwtIssuerOptions
services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
    options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
    options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
});

var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

    RequireExpirationTime = false,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
};

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        cfg.SaveToken = true;

        cfg.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = async (ctx) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ctx.Token);
            },

            OnTokenValidated = async (ctx) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BreakPoint");
            },
        };

        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
    })
    .AddCoinbase(options => {
        options.AccessAllAccounts = true;
        options.SendLimitAmount = 1;
        options.SendLimitCurrency = "USD";
        options.SendLimitPeriod = SendLimitPeriod.day;
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientSecret"];
        COINBASE_SCOPES.ForEach(scope => options.Scope.Add(scope));
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:coinbase:avatar", "avatar_url");
    });
```

I'm making a simple Get Request From Postman using my access_token:

GET https://localhost:44377/api/values
   HEADERS: Authorization: Bearer

However when I inspect the tokens on message received 
I'm always getting null

```
OnMessageReceived = async (ctx) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(ctx.Token);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OnMessageReceived` delegate is called without first setting the `Token` property. For this event, `Token` is something you can set yourself if you're overriding how the token is retrieved. You can see this for yourself in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L54):

```
protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
    string token = null;
    try
    {
        // Give application opportunity to find from a different location, adjust, or reject token
        var messageReceivedContext = new MessageReceivedContext(Context, Scheme, Options);

        // event can set the token
        await Events.MessageReceived(messageReceivedContext);
        if (messageReceivedContext.Result != null)
        {
            return messageReceivedContext.Result;
        }

        // If application retrieved token from somewhere else, use that.
        token = messageReceivedContext.Token;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            string authorization = Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            ...
```

The call to `Events.MessageReceived` invokes your `OnMessageReceived` delegate, but the `MessageReceivedContext` hasn't been initialised with a `Token`, so it's just `null`. After the call to `Events.MessageReceived`, the token is retrieved from the `Authorization` header (if you haven't set it yourself as I mentioned).